# angular2: How to debounce Observable.combineLatest calls?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having performance problems in my angular2 application because I have a big Observable.combineLatest() with many inputs which change quickly and I want to debounce the callback call:

```
myData$ = Observable.combineLatest(
  this.store.let(fromRoot.getFoo),
  this.store.let(fromRoot.getBar),
  this.store.let(fromRoot.getFoobar),
  this.store.let(fromRoot.getBarfoo),
  (foo, bar, foobar, barfoo) => {
     ...
  });
```

Calling debounce after the fact, e.g. Observable.combineLatest(...).debounceTime(300), is useless because the CPU intensive task is happening inside of the combineLatest callback which is still called often.

I guess I have to combine another Observable but I'm not sure how to do it, any ideas?

Comment: What does `store.let` do? It looks like it might be calling the function it's given, perhaps on a timer?

Comment: It gives me an observable from an ngrx store, https://github.com/ngrx/store

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `combineLatest` method's `project` function is essentially a `map` operator. You could re-arrange things like this:

```
myData$ = Observable.combineLatest(
  this.store.let(fromRoot.getFoo),
  this.store.let(fromRoot.getBar),
  this.store.let(fromRoot.getFoobar),
  this.store.let(fromRoot.getBarfoo)
)
.debounceTime(300)
.map(([foo, bar, foobar, barfoo]) => {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

With rxjs > v6 you have to use the rxjs pipe function combined with the debounceTime operator e.g.

```
import {combineLatest, timer} from 'rxjs';
import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';

function testCombineLatest() {

  const startTime = Date.now();
  const timerOne$ = timer(1000, 1000);
  const timerTwo$ = timer(1300, 1000);

  combineLatest(timerOne$, timerTwo$)
    .pipe(debounceTime(600))
    .subscribe(([timer1, timer2]) => {
      console.log('TimeElapsed:', Date.now() - startTime);
      console.log('Timer Latest:', timer1, timer2);
    });
}
testCombineLatest();
```